# Nested for looping in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am facing issue in looping in shell script. I have a requirement where i have to read the content from a flat file and substitue it word by word. For example:

file content is as below:

```
Test1 001
Test2 002
```

and my script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /directorypath/bin/
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        for word1 in $line; do
           nohup ./startcmd.sh attribute1=$word attribute2=$word1      
        done
    done
done < /directorypath/test1.txt
```

but the above snippet is not giving the desired output.

I need the output as below:

```
./startcmd Test1 001
./startcmd Test2 002
```

Can anyone please help me in the same.

Thanks

Comment: Look into using Perl, Python or Ruby for tasks like this

Comment: Why do you have same `for word in $line; do` nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as intended:

```
while read line; do
    nohup ./startcmd.sh $line
done < /directorypath/test1.txt
```

`$line` will contain two words, which will be treated as separate arguments after variable expansion.

**Answer to updated question**

```
while read attrib1 attrib2; do
    nohup ./startcmd.sh attribute1=$attrib1 attribute2=$attrib2
done < /directorypath/test1.txt
```

Comment: Hi, the nohup./startcmd has some attributes: I have to run the command as nohup ./startcmd.sh attribute1=$word attribute2=$word1. So i have to seperate the line contents in words.

Comment: The question does not show `attribute=value` syntax. It shows command line argument syntax. Update the question, then I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated answer for that use case as well.